# How to encrypt a zip file using ansible

Tags: zip, ansible

I have zip file. I have encrypted the zip file using ansible-vault. And able to encrypt. While pushing the encrypted zip file to remote host and unarchive it with ansible, it is throwing error 
msg: Source '/xyz.zip' does not exist.

Is there a way to unarchive the encrypted zip file during the ansible deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions.
First encrypt the xyz.zip with the help of ansible-vault and commit the encrypted zip file to your version control repo.

Then follow the below steps
1. As a local_action = run the ansible-vault decrypt xyz.zip 
2. unarchive the xyz.zip into remote host. Make sure to use ignore_errors: yes. It helps to go to step 3 to encrypt the file again.
3. As a local_action = run ansible-vault encrypt xyz.zip

Done!